# Error al registrar el ServiceWorker : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo aplicaciones web progresivas pero al intentar instalar y activar el serviceworker me genera ese error en la linea 1 del servicio

```
var cacheName = 'weatherPWA-v1.1'; //nombre de la llave de cache
var filesToCache = [
'/',
'/index.html',
'/scripts/app.js'
]; // los elementos que se van al cache

//evento de instalacion del SW
self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
 console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
 e.waitUntil(caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] cache app shell');
  return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
 }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

el error se da en `filesToCache` debes agregar `.` para indicar que se buscara en base a una ruta relativa que dependera de donde se encuentre el archivo en adelante.

```
var cacheName = 'weatherPWA-v1.1'; //nombre de la llave de cache
var filesToCache = [
'./',
'./index.html',
'./scripts/app.js'
]; // los elementos que se van al cache

//evento de instalacion del SW
self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
 console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
 e.waitUntil(caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] cache app shell');
  return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
 }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo error y el problema estaba en el camino de los ficheros en el array filesToCache. Intenta verificar si todos los caminos son correctos.